# Python - Getting Data from JSON

Tags: python, json

I am using an API to get JSON data from an external source and am not sure how to get particular elements from the JSON.

```
json_data = json.loads(resp.text) #resp.text is the response from the API call
print(json_data)
```

Prints the following *(the raw output is single line/flat, so I have formatted to make it more readable)*:

```
[
{'version': {
    'rowVersion': 2044}, 
    'name': 'Administrator', 
    'permissions': [
                        {'path': 'Activity/Cancel All', 'name': 'Activity/Cancel All'}, 
                        {'path': 'Activity/View All', 'name': 'Activity/View All'}, 
                        {'path': 'Audit Log/Edit', 'name': 'Audit Log/Edit'}, 
                        {'path': 'Audit Log/View', 'name': 'Audit Log/View'}
                    ], 
    'id': 1, 
    'permissionPaths': ['Activity/Cancel All', 'Activity/View All', 'Audit Log/Edit', 'Audit Log/View'], 
    'displayName': 'Administrator'
}, 

{'version': {
    'rowVersion': 964033}, 
    'name': 'ViewOnly', 
    'permissions': [
                        {'path': 'Activity/View All', 'name': 'Activity/View All'}, 
                        {'path': 'Audit Log/View', 'name': 'Audit Log/View'}, 
                    ], 
    'id': 4, 
    'permissionPaths': ['Activity/View All', 'Audit Log/View'] 
    'displayName': 'ViewOnly'
}
]
```

The following

```
for ROLES in json_data:
    print(str(ROLES["name"]))
```

Prints:

```
Administrator
ViewOnly
```

So far, so good...
However, I would like the output to be the role and permission name along the lines of...

```
Administrator, Activity/Cancel All
Administrator, Activity/View All
Administrator, Audit Log/Edit
Administrator, Audit Log/View
ViewOnly, Activity/View All
ViewOnly, Audit Log/View
```

Please let me know how I can achieve this in Python.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

json_data = [
{'version': {
    'rowVersion': 2044},
    'name': 'Administrator',
    'permissions': [
                        {'path': 'Activity/Cancel All', 'name': 'Activity/Cancel All'},
                        {'path': 'Activity/View All', 'name': 'Activity/View All'},
                        {'path': 'Audit Log/Edit', 'name': 'Audit Log/Edit'},
                        {'path': 'Audit Log/View', 'name': 'Audit Log/View'}
                    ],
    'id': 1,
    'permissionPaths': ['Activity/Cancel All', 'Activity/View All', 'Audit Log/Edit', 'Audit Log/View'],
    'displayName': 'Administrator'
},

{'version': {
    'rowVersion': 964033},
    'name': 'ViewOnly',
    'permissions': [
                        {'path': 'Activity/View All', 'name': 'Activity/View All'},
                        {'path': 'Audit Log/View', 'name': 'Audit Log/View'},
                    ],
    'id': 4,
    'permissionPaths': ['Activity/View All', 'Audit Log/View'],
    'displayName': 'ViewOnly'
}
]

for ROLES in json_data:
    for n in ROLES["permissions"]:
        print(ROLES["name"], n["name"])
```

**Output:**

```
('Administrator', 'Activity/Cancel All')
('Administrator', 'Activity/View All')
('Administrator', 'Audit Log/Edit')
('Administrator', 'Audit Log/View')
('ViewOnly', 'Activity/View All')
('ViewOnly', 'Audit Log/View')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this task. The next shows the use of list comprehension.

```
for role in json_data:
    print("\n".join(["{role.name}, {permission.name}".format(role=role, permission=permission) for permission in role.permissions]))
```

You can also add a additional for-loop

```
for role in json_data:
    for permission in role.permissions:
        print("{role.name}, {permission.name}".format(role=role, permission=permission))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion, that allows you to get what you want in a list through a one-liner style code. The `for` loop is only here to print each element of the list, if needed:

```
myList = ["{0}, {1}".format(ROLES["name"], perm["name"]) for ROLES in json_data for perm in ROLES['permissions']]
for i in myList:
    print(i)
```